# Is there an appropriate SE site about intersection between technology and rural culture?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, off-topic, scope

My current question is about rural technology, to be specific, this question is more about history and cultural tradition.

[image: Lighting animation as cottage industry] My question falls more into the topic covered by this book.

In which site I can ask more about it?

............

Noteworthy there are other things that fall at the intersection of Technology and tradition - i.e. Handlooms and handmade fabrics, work with rope ties and knots, various kind of fish traps, some special kind of toys for children, etc.

So I am looking for a site which deals the intersection between technology and rural methods and practices.

Edit: **Example question** : provide the actual wiring diagram and photograph (if any) of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/536450/identifying-a-vintage-lighting-sequencer-method/641186#641186) vintage and indigenous light sequencer made by rural people. EESE can provide putative answer and its western analogy, but I am looking more into the actual indigenous technique and its actual wiring diagram.

Comment: If you're asking a question that intersects five totally disparate areas like that, you're asking a question that should not be on Stack Exchange. Narrow it down to something specific, then there might be a site that is appropriate.

Comment: I have erased the extended portion and narrowed it down

Comment: AlwaysConfused, I hope the edit is to your liking: I shortened the beginning, there's no need to complicate your opening with things you are not asking about, and your history of asking elsewhere. --- I was tempted to pare down the second half, but thought I'd leave that to you; as it's less wordy than the first half was.

Comment: @Rob thank you for the edit. I try to convey my question but somehow I fail and I end up with lot of frustration and anxiety. I would be very thankful

Comment: I have totally cleaned up the second portion

Comment: I feel like individual topics might have specific sites good for them. Arts and Crafts comes to mind, as does outdoors. Basically the thing needed here is to focus on the problem, not the topic

Comment: Please provide an example question.

Comment: The example mentioned in context was deleted

Comment: I feel like considering that the things in your example question are probably barely pre ww2 - that they are hardly an 'traditional' creation. There was likely a lot of local creative design and such but its likely they were adopted from designs elsewhere. My mom was born post war and she lived in quite a few (rural) places without mains power